# Goodman motherboard with broken/cut wire

Tags: furnace

I have 2 Goodman furnaces with the same issue. In the middle of the motherboards there is a plug with a red wire and blue wire, and a white wire loop - pictured. My white looped wire is broken or cut. Any thoughts on this? Can I just attach the ends, or is there a reason to leave them apart? It’s been like that for 10 years and both units work fine. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: I have no experience with these, but I'm guessing it's a configuration "setting" that the installer cuts (or does not cut) depending on (something) so I'd say leave it alone. Or: **If it ain't broke, don't "fix" it!**

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace? If it's an installer option, it should be noted there...

Comment: Emphatic +1 to @Ecnerwal 's "If it ain't broke, don't fix it" - you could very well break it.  I would not assume the trimmed leads were originally one piece, but if they were, I'd assume they were cut deliberately.